# What is the difference between atomic and critical in OpenMP?

Tags: openmp, atomic, critical-section

What is the difference between atomic and critical in OpenMP?

I can do this

```cpp
#pragma omp atomic
g_qCount++;
```

but isn't this same as

```cpp
#pragma omp critical
g_qCount++;
```

?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The effect on g_qCount is the same, but what's done is different.

An OpenMP critical section is completely general - it can surround any arbitrary block of code.   You pay for that generality, however, by incurring significant overhead every time a thread enters and exits the critical section (on top of the inherent cost of serialization).

(In addition, in OpenMP all unnamed critical sections are considered identical (if you prefer, there's only one lock for all unnamed critical sections), so that if one thread is in one [unnamed] critical section as above, no thread can enter any [unnamed] critical section.  As you might guess, you can get around this by using named critical sections).

An atomic operation has much lower overhead.  Where available, it takes advantage on the hardware providing (say) an atomic increment operation; in that case there's no lock/unlock needed on entering/exiting the line of code, it just does the atomic increment which the hardware tells you can't be interfered with.

The upsides are that the overhead is much lower, and one thread being in an atomic operation doesn't block any (different) atomic operations about to happen.   The downside is the restricted set of operations that atomic supports.

Of course, in either case, you incur the cost of serialization.

Comment: "you could loose portability" - I'm not sure this is true. The [standard (version 2.0)](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/cspec20.pdf) specifies which atomic operations are allowed (basically things like `++` and `*=`) and that if they aren't supported in hardware, they might be replaced by `critical` sections.

Comment: @DanRoche: Yes, you're quite right.  I don't think that statement was ever correct, I'll correct it now.

Comment: A few days ago I followed a OpenMP tutorial, and as far as I understood, there is a difference in the two different code.

That is the result can differ becaus the critical section assures that the instruction is executed by a thread a time, however it is possible that the instruction:

g_qCount = g_qCount+1;

for thread 1 simply stores the g_qCount result only in the writebuffer not in RAM memory, and when thread 2 fetch the value g_qCount, it simply read the one in the RAM, not in the writebuffer.
Atomic instruction assures the instruction flushed the data to memory

Answer (score 35):

In OpenMP, all the unnamed critical sections are mutually exclusive.

The most important difference between critical and atomic is that atomic can protect only a single assignment and you can use it with specific operators.

Comment: This would have better been a comment (or an edit) of the previous answer.

Answer (score 32):

**Critical section:**

- Ensures serialisation of blocks of code.
- Can be extended to serialise groups of blocks with proper use of "name" tag.
- Slower!

**Atomic operation:**

- Is much faster!
- Only ensures the serialisation of a particular operation.

Comment: But this answer is very readable and would be a great sum up of the first answer

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way is neither critical nor atomic. Approximately, addition with critical section is 200 times more expensive than simple addition, atomic addition is 25 times more expensive then simple addition.

The fastest option (not always applicable) is to give each thread its own counter and make reduce operation when you need total sum.

Comment: I disagree with all numbers you mention in your explanation. Assuming x86_64, the atomic operation will have a few cycle overhead (synchronizing a cache line) on the cost of roughly a cycle. If you would have a ''true sharing'' cost otherwise, the overhead is nihil. A critical section incurs the cost of a lock. Depending on whether the lock is already taken or not, the overhead is roughly 2 atomic instructions OR two runs of the scheduler and the sleep time - that will usually be significantly more than 200x.

Comment: The option you are suggesting might lead to a huge request on memory that we might don't have at our disposal. For instance if I'm working on data of 1000x1000x1000 cells and that I'm working with 10 or 100 threads, the internal copies created for each thread will for sure saturate the RAM.

Answer (score 6):

The limitations of `atomic` are important. They should be detailed on the [OpenMP specs](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fhhcxk3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offers a quick cheat sheet as I wouldn't be surprised if this will not change. (Visual Studio 2012 has an OpenMP implementation from March 2002.) To quote MSDN:

> The expression statement must have one of the following forms:
>
> `x`*binop*=`expr`
>
> `x++`
>
> `++x`
>
> `x--`
>
> `--x`
>
> In the preceding expressions: `x` is an `lvalue` expression with scalar type. `expr` is an expression with scalar type, and it does not reference the object designated by `x`. *binop* is not an overloaded operator and is one of `+`, `*`, `-`, `/`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `<<`, or `>>`.

I recommend to use `atomic` when you can and *named* critical sections otherwise. Naming them is important; you'll avoid debugging headaches this way.

Comment: This are not the all , we have other advanced atomic directives like :
#pragma omp aromic update(or read , upate,write , capture ) so it allows us to have some other beneficial statement

Answer (score 1):

Already great explanations here. However, we can dive a bit deeper. To understand the core difference between the *atomic* and *critical section* concepts in OpenMP, we have to understand the concept of *lock* first. Let's review why we need to use *locks*.

> A parallel program is being executed by multiple threads. Deterministic results will happen if and only if we perform *synchronization* between these threads. Of course, *synchronization* between threads is not always required. We are referring to those cases that *synchronization* is necessary.

In order to *synchronize* the threads in a multi-threaded program, we'll use **lock**. When the access is required to be restricted by only one thread at a time, **lock**s come into play. The **lock** concept implementation may vary from processor to processor. Let's find out how a simple lock may work from an algorithmic point of view.

```
1. Define a variable called lock.
2. For each thread:
   2.1. Read the lock.
   2.2. If lock == 0, lock = 1 and goto 3    // Try to grab the lock
       Else goto 2.1    // Wait until the lock is released
3. Do something...
4. lock = 0    // Release the lock
```

The given algorithm can be implemented in the hardware language as follows. We'll be assuming a single processor and analyze the behavior of locks in that. For this practice, let's assume one of the following processors: **MIPS**, **Alpha**, **ARM** or **Power**.

```
try:    LW R1, lock
        BNEZ R1, try
        ADDI R1, R1, #1
        SW R1, lock
```

This program seems to be OK, but It is not. The above code suffers from the previous problem; *synchronization*. Let's find the problem. Assume the initial value of lock to be zero. If two threads run this code, one might reach the *SW R1, lock* before the other one reads the *lock* variable. Thus, both of them think that the *lock* is free.
To solve this issue, there is another instruction provided rather than simple *LW* and *SW*. It is called *Read-Modify-Write* instruction. It is a complex instruction (consisting of subinstructions) which assures the **lock acquisition** procedure is done by only a **single** thread at a time. The difference of *Read-Modify-Write* compared to the simple *Read* and *Write* instructions is that it uses a different way of *Loading* and *Storing*. It uses *LL*(Load Linked) to load the lock variable and *SC*(Store Conditional) to write to the lock variable. An additional **Link Register** is used to assure the procedure of lock acquisition is done by a single thread. The algorithm is given below.

```
1. Define a variable called lock.
2. For each thread:
   2.1. Read the lock and put the address of lock variable inside the Link Register.
   2.2. If (lock == 0) and (&lock == Link Register), lock = 1 and reset the Link Register then goto 3    // Try to grab the lock
       Else goto 2.1    // Wait until the lock is released
3. Do something...
4. lock = 0    // Release the lock
```

When the link register is reset, if another thread has assumed the lock to be free, it won't be able to write the incremented value to the lock again. Thus, the concurrency of access to the **lock** variable is acquired.

The core difference between *critical* and *atomic* comes from the idea that:

> Why to use locks (a new variable) while we can use the actual variable (which we are performing an operation on it), as a lock variable?

Using a **new** variable for **locks** will lead to **critical section**, while using the **actual** variable as a lock will lead to **atomic** concept. The critical section is useful when we are performing a lot of computations (more than one line) on the actual variable. That's because, if the result of those computations fails to be written on the actual variable, the whole procedure should be repeated to compute the results. This can lead to a poor performance compared to waiting for the lock to be released before entering a highly-computational region. Thus, it is recommended to use the *atomic* directive whenever you want to perform a single computation (x++, x--, ++x, --x, etc.) and use *critical* directive when a more computationally complex region is being done by the intensive section.

Answer (score 1):

`Critical` clause applies mutable exclusion to the code block and guarantees that only one thread will execute the code block at a given time and the thread completes the code block and outs the other threads are Wellcome to acquire the lock for the block to execute.

`Atomic` clause is only applicable to one single statement that has any math symbol in it but the difference is not only limited by the size of the expressions. The atomic clause protects the address location that's assigned the element to the left and only guarantees the assignment to that variable. so you may assume that if any function call exists on the right of the statement it could be executed parallel.

```
#pragma omp atomic
a = 5 + fnk();
```

here `fnk();` could be called by multiple threads at the same time but the assignment to the a must be mutually exclusive.
As you can see below, fnk() call is intervined by another thread and we got the result 0 2 2 and 0 respectively. That would't be the case if we'd used critical clause.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please ignore that the ```count``` is shared variable and the result may be different from iteration to iterations focus on the concurrent function call that occured on the atomic section. but the assignment is executed atomicly.

Answer (score -6):

atomic is a single statement Critical section, i.e. you lock for one statement execution

critical section is a lock on a block of code

A good compiler will translate your second code the same way it does the first

Comment: That's just wrong. Please don't talk about stuff you don't understand.