# OMP Critical Illegally Nested

Tags: c++, critical-section, openmp

I get an error when running my program, which says:

```
A '#pragma omp critical' is illegally nested in one of the same name
```

It dies when it enters one of my criticals.
I am super new to OMP, & this would be my 1st time applying it to large code.

My large code would be too big to paste here, so let me ask 1st & try to figure out what is breaking later.

What does this error even mean? Does that mean "Dont nest #critical"? or is there something specific I screwed up on with names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herp. Thanks to [openMP, atomic vs critical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798010/openmp-atomic-vs-critical), I found that that "name" refered to the name of a critical.

Solved the problem by doing #pragma omp critical(name_here)