# OpenMP atomic memory order

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp, atomic

I started learning OpenMP and discovered the `#pragma omp atomic` directive.

I have basic understanding of C++11's atomics and know that you can pass a `memory_order` parameter to atomics's method.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this allows to use atomics as a synchronization point if using `memory_order_seq_cst` for example.

Some less restrictive memory order, like `memory_order_relaxed` just make sure that the operations on the atomic are synchronized and visible to others. It doesnt nothing about other memory updates.

I would like to know what memory order is used by the OpenMP's atomic directive. Will it only synchronize access to the atomic, or will it act as a memory synchronization's point?

My guess would be that it would be more like `memory_order_relaxed`, because `critical`'s are here to provide a full synchronization.

I welcome any good explanation / informations.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [openMP, atomic vs critical?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798010/openmp-atomic-vs-critical)

Comment: @JustSid This mostly consider lock vs lock-free synchronization primitives, but doesn't explain memory order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OpenMP memory model has been evolving.  Up to and including OpenMP 3.1, the model is based on "flush" operations.  These are not really comparable to anything in the C++ memory model.   Loosely speaking a flush roughly corresponds to atomic_thread_fence(x), where x is memory_order_seq_cst.  But there's a gotcha where it's *not* that if the "intersection of the two flush-sets of the two flushes is empty".

OpenMP 4.0 adds the seq_cst clause, and answers the question directly:

> Note – As with other implicit flush regions, Section 1.4.4 on page 20
>   reduces the ordering that must be enforced. The intent is that, when
>   the analogous operation exists in C++11 or C11, a sequentially
>   consistent atomic construct has the same semantics as a
>   memory_order_seq_cst atomic operation in C++11/C11. Similarly, a
>   non-sequentially consistent atomic construct has the same semantics as
>   a memory_order_relaxed atomic operation in C++11/C11.

For more details, download the [latest version of the spec](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications) (4.0 at this time) and read sections 1.4.4 "OpenMP Memory Consistency" and 2.12.6 "atomic Construct".

Comment: I've expanded the answer.