# General tips to improve multithreading (in C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, prediction

I have build a C++ code without thinking that I would later have the need to multithread it. I have now multithreaded the 3 main for loops with openMP. Here are the performance comparisons (as measured with `time` from bash)

Single thread

```
real    5m50.008s
user    5m49.072s
sys     0m0.877s
```

Multi thread (24 threads)

```
real    1m22.572s
user    28m28.206s
sys     0m4.170s
```

The use of 24 cores have reduced the real time by a factor of 4.24. Of course, I did not expect the code to be 24 times faster. I did not really know what to expect actually.

**- Is there a rule of thumb that would allow one to make prediction about how much faster will a given code run with `n` threads in comparison to a single thread?**

**- Are there general tips in order to improve the performance of multithreaded processes?**

Comment: u have a machine with 24 cores?

Comment: @pm100 yes (24 logical cores). I don't own it, it belongs to my lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you know of the obvious like the cost of barriers. But it's hard to draw a line between what is trivial and what could be helpful to someone. Here are a few lessons learned from use, if I think of more I'll add them:

- Always try to use thread private variables as long as possible, consider that even for reductions, providing only a small number of collective results.
- Prefer parallel runs of long sections of code and long parallel sections (`#pragma omp parallel ... #pragma omp for`), instead of parallelizing loops separately (`#pragma omp parallel for`).
- Don't parallelize short loops. In a 2-dimensional iteration it often suffices to parallelize the outer loop. If you do parallelize the whole thing using `collapse`, be aware that OpenMP will linearize it introducing a fused variable and accessing the indices separately incurs overhead.
- Use thread private heaps. Avoid sharing pools and collections if possible, even though different members of the collection would be accessed independently by different threads.
- Profile your code and see how much time is spent on busy waiting and where that may be occurring.
- Learn the consequences of using different schedule strategies. Try what's better, don't assume.
- If you use critical sections, name them. All unnamed CSs have to wait for each other.
- If your code uses random numbers, make it reproducible: define thread-local RNGs, seed everything in a controllable manner, impose order on reductions. Benchmark deterministically, not statistically.
- Browse similar questions on Stack Overflow, e.g., the wonderful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751294/how-can-i-improve-the-perfomance-of-my-openmp-code?rq=1).